# Definition of German Word "Sicherungssatz" in Backup Context

Tags: translation, compound

I try to find the definition for the german word "Sicherungssatz" used in IT backup context. All articles I find just use the word without explaining it.

The first part of the word "Sicherung" obviously means "backup", but what meaning (if any) does the word "Satz" add?

Is "Sicherungssatz" just a pleonasm of "Sicherung", or does it indicate something specific?

A translation service proposes "set of fuses" as translation, which seems to be a term used in electrical context, but not IT.

Comment: So it seems that this is a rather "Microsoft specific" term? Also "backup set" is specificly adressed here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/media-sets-media-families-and-backup-sets-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#backup-sets

Comment: @BorisDäppen: Microsoft, like many big IT companies, has a very specific and literal way of translating stuff from english to german. AFAIK, translators get a word list that they need to use for terms, which often includes very strange or awkward translations that might never be used in reality. The reason is that they want to create a consistent translation, preventing different translators from using different words for the same context, which is laudable in itself but creates texts that are so hard to read I usually just use the english original instead.

Comment: What does "AFAIK" mean?

Comment: My first idea what *Sicherungssatz* in the context of computer programmes would mean was: a sentence displayed somewhere to avoid legal problems with something, i.e. a "disclaimer". - That's just to demonstrate that the word is not necessarily intuitive. Of course, context would help to get the intended meaning.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "as far as I know"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Sicherungssatz" can be literaly translated with "backup set". Where "backup set" is used, in german it is  "Sicherungssatz" here: [Create a Full Database Backup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Since microsoft has an consistent translation catalogue it can be used to translate technical IT terms. Just replace the `/de-de/`  in the URL to `/en-us/` and you get the translated terms.

Microsoft says according to [Media Sets, Media Families, and Backup Sets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/media-sets-media-families-and-backup-sets-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017):

> backup set: The backup content that is added to a media set by a
>   successful backup operation.

Comment: Technical addition: Usually, a backup set is the combination of full, differential and incremental backups you need to fully restore your data.

Comment: @Sven: "the combination of full, differential and incremental backups", that was my thought, but until now I did not find this explicitely mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Actually it is __one__ backup set. Not all!!

Answer (score 5):

The comment of marsh-wiggle already gives the right answer: It means set of backups. The reason why you can't find it in a dictionary is the feature of the German language to build new compound words by putting two or more words together, written as one word. Since the number of potential compound words that would make sense is practically infinite, it is impossible to have a list of all.

And indeed the meaning depends on context, because "Sicherung" can mean backup, fuse, security, protection, safeguard etc. Without the information that the topic is IT, "set of fuses" would have been the first translation coming to my mind when reading "Sicherungssatz".

edit:
marsh-wiggle converted his comment into an answer while I was writing mine